# Is this use of emmeans an appropriate way to calculate a 95% confidence interval for a parameter?

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, lsmeans

I generated data using the model $y_{i j} = \alpha_i + \beta_i x_{i j} + \epsilon_{i j}, i = 1, \ldots, 48, j = 1, \ldots, 16$, $\alpha_i \sim \text{N}(0, \sigma_{\alpha}^2)$, $\beta_i \sim \text{N}(\mu_{\beta}, \sigma_{\beta}^2)$, $\epsilon_{i j} \sim \text{N}(0, \sigma_{\epsilon}^2)$; I let $\sigma_{\alpha} = 1, \mu_{\beta} = 4, \sigma_{\beta} = 0.5, \text{ and } \sigma_{\epsilon} = 1$. I fit a random coefficient model to the data using the `lme4` package. Below is my code for generating the data and fitting the model:

```r
library(emmeans)
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)

make_dataset <- function(groups, group_size,
                         sigma_alpha, mu_beta, sigma_beta, sigma_epsilon) {
  replicate(
    groups,
    {
      intercept <- rnorm(1, sd = sigma_alpha)
      slope <- rnorm(1, mean = mu_beta, sd = sigma_beta)
      errors <- rnorm(group_size, sd = sigma_epsilon)
      tibble(
        x = seq_len(group_size),
        y = intercept + slope * x + errors
      )
    },
    simplify = FALSE
  ) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = "group") %>%
    mutate(group = as_factor(group))
}

set.seed(1)
dataset <- make_dataset(
  groups = 48, group_size = 16,
  sigma_alpha = 1, mu_beta = 4, sigma_beta = 0.5, sigma_epsilon = 1
)

mod <- lmer(y ~ x + (1 + x | group), dataset)
```

I want to calculate a 95% confidence interval for $\mu_{\beta}$. I know that I can use `confint()` in `lme4` to do this in several different ways. However, I figured out a way to calculate an interval using the `emmeans` package and am wondering whether it's a genuine 95% confidence interval. Below is the code that computes the interval:

```r
mod %>%
  ref_grid(at = list(x = 0:1)) %>%
  emmeans("x") %>%
  pairs(reverse = TRUE) %>%
  confint()
#  contrast estimate     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#  1 - 0        3.98 0.0772 47     3.82     4.14
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
# Confidence level used: 0.95
```

From what I understand, this essentially averages the group-level predictions at $x = 0$, averages the group-level predictions at $x = 1$, and then constructs an interval estimate of the difference between the two averages. This is like computing the slope of the line $y = m x + b$ by setting $x = 0$ to get $b$, setting $x = 1$ to get $m + b$, and then subtracting to get $m + b - b = m$. Is this a valid approach to calculating a 95% confidence interval for $\mu_{\beta}$?

Comment: At first glance this looks o,k but why not use emtrends() and save some steps?

Comment: @RussLenth I wasn't aware of that function - I'll try it out. Thanks.